# Connecting to Data Store from App Engine and Android Studio

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-endpoints

**The Goal:** I'm working on a simple project with Android Studio and Google App Engine. The App is just a Proof of Concept, so nothing spectacular. In a sentence, it is an app that counts the number of times a button was clicked in a six hour interval. Specifically, when a button is hit, the app needs to send a request to the backend. The backend then needs to load a number from cloud storage, increment it, and write it back. Every six hours, I need to reset the counter to zero.

**The Current Progress:** I have the app UI written, I have an App Engine Project set up, and I have the two connected via endpoints. For now, I have a method to send two numbers to be added in the backend and return it. I'll scrap that and go with the incrementor code when the time comes, but I can say I understand how App Engine and Android are connected.

**The Problem:** How do I access Google Cloud Storage programatically from here? Do I write backend code? Do I write code in the App itself? Do I do some more endpoints wizardry?

I keep seeing code excerpts, however, I don't know how everything fits together. I can access cloud storage from the online manager, however, that doesn't do much good I don't think. I understand how buckets and entities are broken down as well, if that helps.

Thanks in advance, I've been wandering through the desert of Documentation for weeks.

Answer (score 0):

It's a little unclear exactly what you're trying to accomplish, but I'll take a crack at hopefully nudging you a bit more in the right direction.

First off, if you're just needing to load and increment a number, in my opinion, you may be far better served using a database, such as Google's Cloud Datastore, rather than Cloud Storage.

There are numerous options for connecting, whether you end up on [Cloud Datastore](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/reference/libraries) or [Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference/libraries). You may find it easiest to implement your Storage/Datastore operations on App Engine, but that really depends on what else you're doing.

If you app just needs to do basic database or storage operations, I wonder if you might not be far better served by a more managed solution like [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/). With Firebase, you get many of Google's cloud services, nicely wrapped in an API that is very easy to implement, thereby negating the need to manage a separate App Engine instance and your endpoints. Firebase also gives you offline and caching functionality.